# How to interpret Microsoft Office 2013 Url format

Tags: url, format, ms-office

I have found that MS Office 2013 is using the following URL format to open documents:

```
ms-word:ofe|u|http://server/folder/file.docx
```

What do these parameters mean: `ofe|u|`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called *Office URI Schemes*.

The initial portion of the URI specifies the application that will be used (ms-word stipulates word)

As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx) ofe allows the application to be opened in editing mode:

> **Edit Document**
>
> The following command will cause the application to open the document referenced by the URI in editing mode.
>
> Command Name: ofe
>
> Command argument descriptor: u
>
> Command argument: a URI to the document, based on the http or https scheme
>
> Example: `ms-powerpoint:ofe|u|http://www.fourthcoffee.com/AllHandsDeck.ppt`

Comment: Will editing the doc will result in changes being saved to PPT directly on server e.g. if any changes are made in presentation on client's machine, would original  AllHandsDeck.ppt  located at http://www.fourthcoffee.com be overwritten with changes?

Comment: @JatinDhoot No it wouldn't.